# iOS: Scaling for different screen sizes with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, screen

I am programming an app for iPhone and I am using Auto Layout. I understand how @1x, @2x and @3x works, but what I don't understand is how to handle different screen sizes with Auto Layout.

If I want a scene to look good both on iPhone 6+, iPhone 6 and iPhone 5, I need to take into account the very different sizes of each phone.  I can't use the same image size (in points) on all iPhones, because it will look too big on smaller phones, or too small on bigger phones. And I don't even want to imagine the hassle of iPad layout.

How can I solve this? Should I use constraints to make all of my images scale dynamically? This sounds doable, but I'm wondering what the best solution is.

Thank you. I'm really at a loss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the propotion on different sizes (for instance an image that has the same apparent size in each device) you can use constraints.

One small trick that I usually do is:

Define an aspect ratio constraint (cmd + click beginning in your view and ending in your view):

[image]

And then force your view to increase in width or in height (ie: defining constraints for the left and the right).

It all depends on what you want actually, and the constraints/code will vary in different situations.

Comment: Is this solution viable for an entire screen? It was what I was thinking of doing, but I didn't know about the "Aspect Ratio" constraint. What exactly does it do, in comparison with just defining constraints for left and right (which should also stretch the image)?

What solution do you use in your own apps for the issue I'm facing? I would assume it's a rather universal problem.

Thank you.

Comment: The difference between Aspect Ratio vs Non Aspect Ratio is that this way you guarantee that if you increase the width the image will have the same ratio and increase the height in the same ratio as well. As I said, it all depends on your concrete problem. You might want to increase the size of your image to a maximum size, or increase your image with the same ratio as other images, or even simply go full screen. Usually I solve this with constraints, but ofc the constraints are different for each case.

Comment: Okay. I will try adding these types of constraints, basically aspect ratio and left/right or top/bottom constraints in order to make my subviews resize dynamically. How would you increase the image's size with the same ratio as other images in this way though?

Comment: You can also establish a ratio between images. If you ctrl drag beginning in one image and ending in another and select width or height you create a relation between the width of your first image and the width of the second image.

Comment: I've been making progress with resizing most of my images. But I still have issues with some images that are more independent from the rest. In my view I have several images related to one another vertically, so they all resize automatically quite well thanks to top and bottom constraints, and one or two left and right constraints.

But I also have some images that are much smaller, and I don't know how to resize them. I could do a bottom/top constraint in points but it wouldn't work for all views. With multipliers it seems a bit random / unpredictable. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you could make the @2x and @3x unproportionally bigger than its @1x counter part, then use the UIImageView's intrinsic size to let it become bigger for the different screen sizes

never tried something like this myself but i dont see a reason why it wouldnt work

Comment: It doesn't work very well because @2x is used for iPhone 4, iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, all of which have quite different screen sizes. Basically a solution like that is great for 4 and 5 but it doesn't work out at all for 6.